# Issues with adding foreign key constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server, and I need to add a foreign key to an already existing table.

The issue is the column which will act as the foreign key already has a few inconsistent values (which do not occur as a primary key) in another table.

I was wondering, when I alter the table and add the foreign key constraint, what will happen to the rows in the table with foreign key constraint , which has inconsistent values??

--Neeraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is your decision. You can leave this values in table using WITH NOCHECK clause. But all new inserted values will be checked.

Comment: or if you don't specify `WITH NOCHECK` then the FK constraint will not be created since there are zombie rows in the child table...

Comment: What exaclty does NO CHECK do??

Comment: it is possible create foreign key with invalidate data BEFORE you create this.In other word, FK will be created but no existing data check will be done.When you will insert new data, it will be checked.

Comment: This will also mean anytime a legacy row is updated that the update will fail unless the FK is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an error and nothing will be inserted.

To find all inconsistent rows (supposing that `A` and `B` are the target tables, `A.id` is a parent key and `B.fk_id` is a child, foreign key, id):

```
   SELECT B.fk_id
     FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON A.id = B.fk_id
    WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

After executing it you'll have all child rows that refers to "nowhere". So you either need to remove them, modify to point to the existing rows or set `B.fk_id` to `NULL` (if there is no `NOT NULL` constraint).

And after that query returns 0 rows - you can safely create foreign key constraint without any magic options.

Comment: @Neeraj: fix the data to be consistent and create constraint. Otherwise it is pointless to use constraints at all.

Comment: @zerkms: ok.. but incase I do not remove those specific keys, what issues can I face , when I alter the table, I am talking about issues like rows dissapearing on their own coz they have an inconsistent Foreign key, or any issues related to data loss.

Comment: @Neeraj: until you make your data consistent - it is pointless to create foreign key constraints. Because the data is not-trusted.

Comment: @zerkms : the data is inconsistent right now ,but we have changes the service layer, such that, in the future if there foreign keys being added, which are inconsistent, then a similar primary key will be added to the required table, with the necessary data.And with the frequency of updates to this table, it will not take more than a day that the tables will have consistent data.But for that to happen, first we need to add this constraint and let nature take its course.I hope that solves the issue of initial inconsistent data?

Comment: @Neeraj: from my point of view - not. You can select all inconsistent rows with trivial `LEFT JOIN` and fix it to correct values.

Comment: @zerkms : probably I get your point.Can you please point me to a few turotials which will help me remove such data using joins??(as you might have guessed, im a noob)

Comment: @Neeraj: I updated my answer with query and few explanations.